# bar chart some x axis values missing in amchart

Tags: html, json, amcharts

In Amcharts ,some category fields(X axis values) missing in barchart. I have more than 200 x axis values. Please check the below code.

```
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "startDuration": 2,
    "dataProvider": [
        {
            "country": "Applications & Analytics",
            "visits": 765,
            "color": "#FF6600"
        },
        {
            "country": "Common Software Foundation",
            "visits": 1,
            "color": "#FF6600"
        },
        {
            "country": "Customer Doc",
            "visits": 1,
            "color": "#FF6600"
        },
        ........
        .......
        ........
        {
            "country": "LTE",
            "visits": 2,
            "color": "#FF6600"
        },
        {
            "country": "Radio Standards II",
            "visits": 6,
            "color": "#FF6600"
        },

    ],
    "valueAxes": [{ 
         "position": "left", 
         "title": "Visitors" 
    }], 
    "graphs": [{ 
         "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>", 
         "fillColorsField": "color", 
         "valueAxis.dashLength": 5,
         "fillAlphas": 1, 
         "lineAlpha": 0.1, 
         "type": "column", 
         "valueField": "visits" 
    }], 
    "chartCursor": { 
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false, 
        "cursorAlpha": 0, 
        "zoomable": false 
    }, 
    "categoryField": "country", 
    "categoryAxis": { 
        "categoryAxis.dashLength":100,
        "categoryAxis.gridPosition": "start",
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "autoGridCount": "true",
        "gridPosition": "start", 
        "autoGridCount": "true",
        "labelRotation": 90
    }, 
    "export": { 
        "enabled": true 
    } 
}); 
</script> 

<!-- HTML --> 
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Please find image for more clarity. Bar 215 get created, but field value is not displaying for all the bar.

Please suggest me how can i get all the x axis text in bar.

[image]

Comment: You say, we should "find image", but how are we supposed to "find image", if there is no image?

Comment: Sorry Geshode, i have updated image link . https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyeZf.png

Comment: Try adding a horizontal scroll bar to the div class

Comment: Sorry, i need chart without scrollbar @ Binara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `"minHorizontalGap": 0` in your `"categoryAxis"`, like this:

```
"categoryAxis": { 
    "categoryAxis.dashLength":100,
    "categoryAxis.gridPosition": "start",
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "autoGridCount": "true",
    "gridPosition": "start", 
    "autoGridCount": "true",
    "labelRotation": 90,
    "minHorizontalGap": 0
}
```

The default gap is set to 75, which causes the labels not to be seen by such a large number of labels.

Comment: Thank you, now its showing all the values. but looks text are overlapping.Is there any way to give space between texts. i will attach image link with this question for more clarity.

Comment: You can set `"minHorizontalGap"` to a higher number than 0 and see at which setting it looks the way you want it to be.

Comment: If it solves your problem, then please choose the answer, so that the question can be closed.

Comment: ya , its almost solved my problem. but some x axis values missing again after set "minHorizontalGap" to a higher number than 0, because of space issue i guess. is there any way to reduce text size?

Comment: To change the font size of the axis, you can add "fontSize" the same way you have added "minHorizontalGap" and then put the number, which you want. Maybe it is necessary to try some settings to find the best one for you.